# Error markers missing in Pydev Eclipse after Remove PyDev Project Config

Tags: python, eclipse, error-handling, pydev, marker

I'm using pydev eclipse. I encountered an import error and I followed instructions on the internet and did this "`RClick --> PyDev --> Remove PyDev Project Config`". And now the red error markers are all gone. I'm panicking right now, I don't understand anything, now I can't get the error markers back.

Please, anyone, tell me how to get the red markers error back? Is there any way to "Add Pydev Project Config" back? I try to restart, update,.... but none of them work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing `PyDev Project Config` means that you just said to the project that you don't want PyDev to analyze anything.

You can right-click it again and choose `PyDev > Set as PyDev project` and configure your source folders (i.e.: the folders that should be in the PYTHONPATH) as explained in: https://www.pydev.org/manual_101_project_conf2.html to get your error markers back (as PyDev will only analyze files under a source folder).